# Cucumber can't find routes? This is potentially a big newb question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

Rails3 app with Rspec2 and Cucumber

**Cucumber**

```
Given /^that a user is logged in$/ do
  current_user = User.first
  render new_user_post_path(current_user)
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
map.resources :users do |users|
  users.resources :posts, :collection => {:view => :get}
end
```

**posts_controller_spec**

```
describe PostsController do
  describe "#new" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

**My first big epic Fail**

```
(::) failed steps (::)

No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"new"} (ActionController::RoutingError)
./features/step_definitions/tasklist_steps.rb:3:in `/^that a user is logged in$/'
features/tasklist.feature:7:in `Given that a user is logged in'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/tasklist.feature:6 # Scenario: List SubmitLink

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
0m0.147s
rake aborted!
```

Sorry, I'm too newb. This is my first ever attempt at cucumber. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first off map is deprecated in Rails 3 routes, you should probably have something like this.

```
resources :users do 
    resources :posts
end
```

The way I normally write my givens, I follow the path that the user would actually take, create the user in the test db, and then actually going to the login page and signing in, so everything gets set correctly in the app.

```
Given /^I have one user "([^\"]*)" with email "([^\"]*)" and password "([^\"]*)"$/ do |username,email, password|
  @user = User.new(:email => email,
                   :username=>username,
                   :password => password,
                   :password_confirmation => password)
   @user.save!
end

Given /^I am an authenticated user$/ do
  name = 'exmample'
  email = 'example@example.com'
  password = 'secret!'

  Given %{I have one user "#{name}" with email "#{email}" and password "#{password}"}
  And %{I go to the user login page}
  And %{I fill in "user_username" with "#{name}"}
  And %{I fill in "user_password" with "#{password}"}
  And %{I press "Sign in"}
end
```

I use it the following way:

```
Feature: 
  In order to reboot my crappy/POS equipment without bothering the awesome Noc Monkeys
  I would like to login to a webpage and see the status of and control the outlets on my equipment

  Background: Valid and authenticated user with at least one outlet to control
    Given I am an authenticated user

  @ok
  Scenario: Viewing All outlets
    Given I am able to control an outlet with index "1"
    And I am on the home page
    Then I should see "server_1"
```

Also, normally I don't call render inside a cucumber step. Since you are working with a simulated browser (assuming webrat/capybara) you would  `visit path_to(page_name)`.

Comment: Righteo. I figured it out. Thanks a bazillion. I'm sure I'll fall in a dozen more pitfalls between now and being an even lesser newb ;) . Thanks for the help.